# getMinutes() and getHours() seem to change the time in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm reading times from a spreadsheet, but when I use the `getMinutes` or `getHours` function the time appears to change. 
The time value is held in `wholeDay[1][c]`, and should be incrementing in 15 minutes intervals (00:00, 00:15, etc). In both examples below **the time should be 00:30**.

When I log the time alone, as shown on the second log line in both examples, it appears to be correct.

What obvious thing am I overlooking?

### getMinutes

```
Logger.log(wholeDay[1][c] + " : " + wholeDay[1][c].getMinutes());
Logger.log(wholeDay[1][c]);
```

Result:

```
[15-09-07 23:17:59:041 WAT] Sat Dec 30 1899 01:16:24 GMT+0100 (WAT) : 16
[15-09-07 23:17:59:042 WAT] Sat Dec 30 00:30:00 GMT+00:13 1899
```

### getHours

```
Logger.log(wholeDay[1][c] + " : " + wholeDay[1][c].getHours());
Logger.log(wholeDay[1][c]);
```

Result:

```
[15-09-07 23:14:47:522 WAT] Sat Dec 30 1899 01:16:24 GMT+0100 (WAT) : 1
[15-09-07 23:14:47:523 WAT] Sat Dec 30 00:30:00 GMT+00:13 1899
```

## Update

I've updated the logging to call `getMinutes` twice, however the error is consistent.

```
Logger.log(wholeDay[1][c] + " : " + wholeDay[1][c].getMinutes());
Logger.log(wholeDay[1][c] + " : " + wholeDay[1][c].getMinutes());
Logger.log(wholeDay[1][c]);
```

Results

```
[15-09-08 07:42:01:421 WAT] Sat Dec 30 1899 01:16:24 GMT+0100 (WAT) : 16
[15-09-08 07:42:01:422 WAT] Sat Dec 30 1899 01:16:24 GMT+0100 (WAT) : 16
[15-09-08 07:42:01:423 WAT] Sat Dec 30 00:30:00 GMT+00:13 1899
```

Comment: I added an extra line of logging in an attempt to see if this is the cause, however the error is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the timezones are set the same on both the spreadsheet and the script. They are separate settings.